# Show PyCharm right margin?

Tags: 14.10

Updated from 14.04 to 14.10. Now PyCharm is starting with its vertical line in the middle of the editor. Searched the entire settings and couldn't a find solution. This [article](http://tiku.io/questions/2853887/github-atom-remove-the-center-line-in-the-editor) talks about disabling the "wrap-guide" or edit "stylesheet"?

Comment: What do you mean vertical line in the middle of the editor, ? There is multiple options in Pycharm where lines in the editor are optional, which one are you talking about  ?

Comment: Picture and code example in the article.

Comment: This article are mainly talking about Atom Editor! and not Pycharm this code is to  Atom configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertical line in the picture can be disabled by going to Settings. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or from File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Unbox *Right Margin*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In PyCharm there is a vertical line at 120 columns to indicate a suggested maximum line length. To disable the vertical line:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General, select Right margin, uncheck the checkbox for Foreground
```